# GLEW doesn't work in own library

Tags: c++, opengl, segmentation-fault, glew

I have created a library which use GLEW and I have the next piece of code:

```
// ShaderProgram.hpp
#include <GL.hpp>
#include <vector>

namespace LIBRARY {
    class LIBRARY_API ShaderProgram {
    public:
        ShaderProgram() {
            // If I uncomment the code will works, but why it doesn't work without because I already initialize GLEW in the main() function
            // glewExperimental = GL_TRUE;
            // std::cout << (glewInit() == GLEW_OK) << "\n"; // <- Outputs true

            std::cout << (glCreateProgram) << "\n" // <- Null function!
            m_program = glCreateProgram(); // <- Here crash when trying to call glCreateProgram(), I mean it can't find the function
        }
    };
}
```

And that is a part of my library code. Then I created a small app to test it and I use SFML for window:

```
int main() {
...

sf::Window window(sf::VideoMode(800, 600, 32), "OpenGL", sf::Style::Titlebar | sf::Style::Close, settings);
window.setFramerateLimit(60);

window.setActive(true);

glewExperimental = GL_TRUE;
std::cout << (glewInit() == GLEW_OK) << "\n"; // <- Outputs true

std::cout << (glCreateProgram) << "\n" // <- Not null function adress, so it's good!     

LIBRARY::ShaderProgram shaderProgram; // <- Here crash
...
```

So, in the main() the glCreateProgram is not null, it a callable function, but in the library is null and I can't understand why because I call the library code after the glew init as it can see in the code where I construct the ShaderProgram.

```
Thread 1 received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x00000000 in ?? ()
(gdb) bt
#0  0x00000000 in ?? ()
#1  0x68a015a2 in LIBRARY::ShaderProgram::ShaderProgram() ()
   from path\to\my\library.dll
#2  0x00401843 in main ()
```

I don't understand why in the app GL works, but in the library it doesn't.

EDIT: Edited the code to explain better the problem.

Comment: Compile your DLL + EXE in debug configurations, and start it with a debugger. It might tell you the problem right away.

Comment: Also, you might want to look at, and/or reuse, this project of mine: https://github.com/Const-me/GL3Windows (MIT license). It’s small but reasonably complete modern OpenGL sample for Windows, with GLEW, shaders and VBOs.

Comment: Use [#include guards](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Include_guard) in your GL.hpp and see if it helps.

Comment: The last output is from the debugger

I have include guards everywhere.
The problem is that the library can't find the opengl function even if in the main() opengl works and GLEW initialized successfully.

Comment: How did you know Glew initialized successfully? Printing "IT's OK" is done whatever happened before. GBD is telling that glCreateProgram address is 0, which means glew didn't give you that function pointer.

Comment: I know it's ok because I check the output of Engine::initialize() and is 1

Comment: Then I suspect of your use of namespaces.

Comment: Edited the code to explain better the problem.

Comment: You should be aware of the fact that both your library and your main program have each a _separate_ copy of all of GLEW's function pointers, and intializing one does not intialize the others.

Comment: But why? If I uncomment the code to initialize GLEW in `ShaderProgram` I still get the same crash from other classes from library so it means that it only initialize for the class `ShaderProgram`.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that I was linking GLEW statically. Resolved by linking dynamically.